# Unable to access shared folder

Tags: permissions, sharing

I'm using VirtualBox on Windows 7 with xubuntu guest.  I set up guest additions and am able to copy between the clipboards.

I'm trying to share C:\share on my host machine.  I have it set up as /media/sf_share.  When I do a "cd sf_share" from /media, I get a Permission Denied error.

```
dev@dev-VirtualBox:/media$ id
uid=1000(dev) gid=1000(dev) groups=1000(dev),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)

drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Apr  4 02:58 media/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Apr  4 02:58 media/
```